# Do modern browsers block <a href="javascript:window.open....?

Tags: javascript, html, css, browser

I want to pop up a window for people to share to Facebook.

The only way to do this is through javascript. (pop up a small window width=400, height=200)

Will Chrome/IE/Google pop up blockers block this?

How to get around it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Modern browsers will not block what you're attempting to do.

All modern browsers do implement tech to block popups. What this means is all window.open calls must be within a click event handler, or within a function called by said handler. As long as you are creating a pop up in response to a user action you should be fine.

If you are attempting to call window.open as soon as the dom is loaded, or after a short delay (example: setTimeout(50, window.open())) then it will be blocked.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use popups – use a javascript modal window, with the href pointed to real content if appropriate.

For most users, popups are very annoying.